# How can I add caption files at the same time as I upload videos to YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I have 100 .mp4 video files that I want to upload to YouTube. For each .mp4 file I have a .srt file ([caption file](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734698)) with the same file name. Is there any way I can upload all videos *and* caption files at once? We can upload several videos by drag and drop, but I wonder if there is any similar bulk upload option for caption files.